# Azure Message Bus and batch consumer with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: azure, spring-cloud-stream

I use library: com.microsoft.azure:spring-cloud-azure-servicebus-topic-stream-binder:1.2.7 the documentation is pure and I can not find if the Spring Cloud Stream with this binder can do batch processing consumer. Does anybody implement a batch processing consumer with Spring Cloud Stream and Azure Message Bus?

Comment: hi did you found any solution. I'm not able to configure sample app to use this library for simple event processing.

Comment: Hi. We use it in production for single message processing and works well.

Comment: Hi, we check it and even the Azure service bus does not support acknowledgment for a batch. It seems that there will not also be any implementation for batch binder